# How to take backup of schema postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Hi I am currently using postgresql and deleting some of the tables for testing purpose and I want to take backup of schema. can any one let me know how to do that ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You export only `schema without data` using `pg_dump` in `psql [terminal]`:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -s databasename > backup.sql
```

or with `Pgadmin4`

1. Go to `Tool -> Backup` and select `only schema` in the `Dump option`.

[image: Screenshot of Backup]

Comment: it is not clear from the answer, but with `pg_dump` the parameter you need is `-s` in order to dump schema only.